# Getting an iOS app build on someone elses iDevice?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect, provisioning, ipa

I'm not sure if this question has been asked before but what are the exact steps I'll need to follow to get my app which is still in development onto someone elses iDevice when all I have of his iDevice is its device ID.

What I tried doing is adding the device to the 'devices' section of my provisioning portal, then I downloaded the provisioning profile of the app and sent the provisioning profile with the compiled IPA to this person.

From his end what should he do? I told him to just drag the IPA into iTunes and see what happens.

Is that what I should be doing or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have make correct provisioning profile for testing devices, then drag drop the ipa build to iTunes and sync your device.
 There is another alternative way for easy installation, expore [testflight](http://testflightapp.com/)

Comment: Testflight is amazing and provides some detailed feedback on installs, crashes etc.

Answer (score 1):

What you do is correct and it should work. If you have distribution profile you don't need deviceId too.